# Does the string <!-FTCACHE-1-> in a PDF file mean anything?

Tags: pdf

My program downloads a PDF file from a source location every day. When I see the binary text of the PDF file in Notepad, I find that sometimes the PDF file has the string `<!-FTCACHE-1->` at the end. Sometimes this word is missing from the PDF file.

My program downloads this PDF daily and compares it with the previous day's PDF file using the Windiff binary comparison.

99% of the time, Windiff reports differences in the PDF file just because one PDF contains the string `<!-FTCACHE-1->` at the end.

Does anyone knows what the reason behind this is?

Thanks,
Praveen

Answer (score 2):

`<!--FTCACHE-1-->` is generated by FatWire Content Server, a web content management solution that is probably generating your URL.  FTCACHE means FutureTenseCache, the name of the original product component.  The text is a "footer" flag that indicates to the caching module whether or not the page was properly generated.  If the page is supposed to be cached, a 1 indicates that the page was properly built, and so is cacheable.  If 0 is returned, it indicates that the page was corrupted and should not be cached.  The Satellite Server caching engine is supposed to strip this footer once it reads it.

In other words, the key that is there to ensure that the cache is not corrupted, is causing the corruption in your PDF.

This issue has been fixed in patches to FatWire ContentServer for quite some time now.

For your purposes, just ignore the string - strip it if you can.

Sorry about that.  That was my bug. :-)

Answer (score 1):

The application that generates the PDF file has a bug, the FTCACHE tag should not be there, it is not a valid PDF construct. Its presence actually damages the PDF file, it invalidates the FastWebView feature in the PDF file, as you have seen it. It is safe to remove it before comparing the files.

Answer (score 0):

"FT" could be [FreeType](http://www.freetype.org/index2.html), the open source font engine. The comment probably comes from the software that generates the PDF. If you can somehow identify that, you could (assuming it is open source) perhaps take a look through it and see what causes it to emit the comment.

FreeType has a [source folder](http://git.savannah.gnu.org/cgit/freetype/freetype2.git/tree/src/cache) dedicated to caching, the root source file there is called [ftcache.c](http://git.savannah.gnu.org/cgit/freetype/freetype2.git/tree/src/cache/ftcache.c). It doesn't do a lot though, just `#include`s (!) the other source files.

Googling on the string you see, reveals several more or less random PDF:s that seem to contain it.

Comment: I found something with further analysis that if I delete this string from the file and check the file properties then Fast Web Access becomes true. If I again add it then Fast Web Access becomes false.

So is there something in downloading the file that sometime Fast Web Access is true or false?